# WPF (mvvm) databinding itemssource and selecteditem to different models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I've got a WPF databinding issue that I'm not getting past. I have an MVVM setup like the following:

```
public class ModelA
{
    public int Id
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}

public class ModelB
{
    public ModelA The_A
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelA> ModelAList
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelB> ModelBList
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

My XAML's DataContext is ViewModel (surprise), and I've got this ListBox in it:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ModelBList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ModelAList"
                SelectedItem="{Binding The_A}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I open my window, the ComboBox does not have an item selected, yet if I select something from the checkbox, The_A gets set to whatever I selected.

My guess is that the ModelA's in my ModelAList are different from the ModelA's in the ModelB's. Is there a way I can make this databinding work? Perhaps I'm missing something obvious or I'm not attacking the problem correctly.

Thanks much!

Comment: In check box bind to `<CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding yourbinding, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

Comment: Oh dear, I used a CheckBox instead of a ComboBox. I meant to use a combobox, hence the selecteditem and itemssource properties. I apologize for that!

Setting the mode to TwoWay has no effect, unfortunately, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Good to hear that. That's happens.. Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bit of finagling, I've found the solution to the problem. IDisposable's answer here points out that the combobox cannot bind to two separate objects at once. Therefore, when the ViewModel is instantiated (and after the list of ModelA's has been loaded), the list can be copied into each ModelB for binding. The solution is below.

```
public class ModelA
{
    public int Id
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}

public class ModelB
{
    public ModelA The_A
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelA> The_A_List
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        //Load lists
        foreach (var b in ModelBList)
        {
            b.The_A_List = ModelAList;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelA> ModelAList
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelB> ModelBList
    {
        //Property uses INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

This then affords the following binding in the xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ModelBList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding The_A_List}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding The_A}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And all is well. Thanks again to IDisposable for the help and setting me on the path to enlightenment.

Answer (score 3):

Your data binding seems to be wrong. That is why it doesn't work.
Since your view binds to `ViewModel` class surprisingly, that `ViewModel` class is supposed to hold all the bindings from the corresponding view.

Well you have your itemssource bound correctly to the ModelAList IEnumerable.

But the selected item is bound to some other class' property. Hence it will not work. Also you need to set the selected item to the data type that is used for your itemssource also.

Hence create a property in the `ViewModel` class as follows :

```
private ModelA _selectedComboBoxItem;
public ModelA SelectedComboBoxItem
{
    get { return _selectedComboBoxItem; }
    set 
    { 
       _selectedComboBoxItem = value; 
       Propertychanged(this, "SelectedComboBoxItem");
    }
}
```

Then bind it to the SelectedItem as follows :

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem}"
```

This should obviously work.

**EDIT :**
Adding more details as requested by asker.

Suppose you have a dozen of oranges with you. If you get a person to pick randomly from them, what do you get? An Orange itself right? That’s the idea behind this also. If you select a combobox item, it will be of the very same type as its source.

If you have many comboboxes in the same list item, you could change the ItemsSource datatype to hold that many lists or properties.

For eg : Say I have  a list with 2 combobox and 2 textbox. So my itemssource would be ObservableCollection and this observable collection would hold 2 enumerables as well as 2 strings for holding the 4 control’s values. You could also create 2 additional properties for binding the selected items of each combobox if you wish.

Comment: As you can see, I want to be able to set the "The_A" property in each ModelB in ModelBList with this binding, I'm afraid your solution doesn't quite cut it here (there are multiple checkboxes in the listbox).

Comment: Is it simply impossible to bind to two different objects in that manner? If so, is there some other way to get the desired behavior?

P.S. I meant "combobox" above, not checkbox, my bad!

Comment: I have edited the answer and added more information as per your doubts. Please check.

Comment: I'm afraid I might be explaining my problem wrong. My ViewModel contains a list of ModelB's, and a list of all the possible ModelA's which exist in my application at that time. Each ModelB has it's own ModelA property, which I desire to set via databinding here. As you'll see, the itemssource of my listbox is set to the list of ModelB's in the ViewModel, and the itemssource of each individual combocox is set to the list of all ModelA's (which must reside in the viewmodel). (1/2)

Comment: Then, because each of the ModelB's to which I am binding have their own ModelA property, I endeavour to bind the selected item of that list which contains all ModelA's to that ModelA item in each individual ModelB. Does this add some clarity to my problem? As it stands, your suggestion is to place one "SelectedItem" property in the ViewModel, which you can see is insufficient considering I have many comboboxes, bound to many ModelB's. (2/2)

Comment: I'm going to proceed under the assumption that the databinding as I need it is unavailable to me, and I may need to perform some major surgery on the application. Also, I do very much appreciate your responding to my query, it has been quite helpful indeed!

Comment: Yes. It's not possible. The source of the listbox is IEnumerable<ModelB>. Hence the combobox in that listbox should be bound to an IEnumerable<ModelA> and this IEnumerable shall be placed inside ModelB class. Hope you got the point. ModelB class also shall contain the selected combobx item ie `public ModelA SelectedComboBoxItem`. If you want to have a selected item of the listbox you can have it in the ViewModel class itself as `public ModelB SelectedListItem`

Comment: Hope you got the point. There's not much complication. Just need to understand the hierarchy level.

Comment: Rest assured, I understand you just fine. The problem is perhaps beyond what you're able to help me with.

Comment: It's the most feasible solution for your problem. Maybe if you could find some other solution it would be pretty fine!

Comment: Yeah, the problem I keep running into is that I need the data to be stored in the model, so having the selected items in the viewmodel kinda hurts the app. Ah! Perhaps if I were to move the itemssource from the viewmodel into the model on construction... I'll give that a shot here.

Comment: You can obviously keep the combobox selected item in ModelB for each list item. I think that is the problem you're facing now. Atleast from next time, while you're asking a question add entire code, rather than demo code. It will be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to remember that :)